# What's the difference between ups void(cancellation) and return shipment

Tags: return, void, ups

I am developing ups Integration right now! The ups shiping Api provide developers shipping service, void service and return service. My question is when should I send void request and when should I send return shipping request?
Please help me figure this out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Void: cancel the shipment.
Return: a special shipment that shipping the product from your customer to you.